# How to yield an array by choosing items to add

Tags: f#

I have the following array

```
let evens = [| 
    for key in numbersDictionary.Keys -> 
        match numbersDictionary.[key] % 2
        | 0 -> Some(numbersDictionary.[key])
        | _ -> None |]
```

I do have the array of option types with `None` for odd numbers. How do I tweak the above statement so `evens` becomes `int[]` instead of `int option []` and no `None`s ?

Comment: are you sure this is working? You don't fetch your key from `numbersDictionary.Keys`

Comment: @CarstenKönig I guess I am bad at typing on this website. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
let evens =
  numbersDictionary
  |> Seq.map (fun kvp -> kvp.Value)
  |> Seq.filter (fun v -> v % 2 = 0)
  |> Seq.toArray
```

even simpler:

```
let evens =
  numbersDictionary.Values
  |> Seq.filter (fun v -> v % 2 = 0)
  |> Seq.toArray
```

or closer to your question:

```
let evens =
   [| for v in dict.Values do if v%2=0 then yield v |]
```

Comment: We are now building Seq then an Array as opposed to just the array, how is it different in performance ?

Comment: You iterate the dictionary anyway using it's `GetEnumerator` - I don't think there is any relevant difference but you should try if you really need to look at performance

Answer (score 2):

your code is equal to:

```
let evens' = [| 
    for key in numbersDictionary.Keys do        
        yield //always yields into Array
            match numbersDictionary.[key] % 2 with 
            | 0 -> Some(numbersDictionary.[key])
            | _ -> None |]
```

`->` is just written as `do yield`

now by moving the `yield` inside the match expression you can achieve the desired result:

```
let evens'' = [| 
    for key in numbersDictionary.Keys do        
        match numbersDictionary.[key] % 2 with
        | 0 -> yield numbersDictionary.[key] //only yields this into Array
        | _ -> ()  |]
```